# Countries up to date?

Tags: contacts, addresses

in CiviCRM 5.15.2 (but also in 5.17.2 alpha on the CiviCRM demo site) the country North Macedonia is still referred to as: Macedonia, Republic of.

Users can not change this themselves obviously. 
[In the documentation](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/i18n+Administrator's+Guide:+Using+CiviCRM+in+your+own+language#i18nAdministrator'sGuide:UsingCiviCRMinyourownlanguage-CountriesandProvinces) it is stated: 
*The installed CiviCRM database contains both an ISO 3166-1-compliant list of countries, and a full, ISO 3166-2-compliant list of provinces (states, departments, voivodships, etc.).*

However, this does not seem to be the case.

Can somebody tell me if CiviCRM needs updating the countries (or may be I should add my question somewhere else?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes at the moment the list is manually maintained (see https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.15.2/xml/templates/civicrm_country.tpl#L172). You can file an update request at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues

Comment: @betty-dolfing Looks like you filed one at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1166 and there has been an update done at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15997 which should be in version 5.21.

Answer (score 1):

The particular issue is resolved in CiviCRM 5.21: See [release notes](https://civicrm.org/blog/dev-team/civicrm-521-release)

- **Countries: Renamed "Macedonia, Republic of" to "North Macedonia".**

others have commented on the wider point.

Answer (score 0):

The country/province lists *do not* have the correct ISO 3166 numeric ids (ex 1228 for USA should be 240.

This is important because everyone else uses ISO ids and in order to map the right country IDs for civi, you need to create a mapping table. PITA. Get it right!

As well the country names do not all match.

Why not just use the ISO data dumps to create these tables, like the rest of the world does? >SMH<

This becomes very important when you need to create forms with addresses in them. You have to use one ID for civi and the correct ID for everything else....

Comment: It's a fair point but the way stackexchange works this is likely to get downvoted because it's not an answer to the question that was asked. Can you instead repost this as a suggestion at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues?

Comment: Done... https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1509 
Thx for suggestion!